# How to prevent accidental touches when opening Drawer Navigator?

Tags: react-native, gesture, react-navigation-drawer

I want to use `<Text selectable={true}>`, which is in `<SectionList />`. But when I open Drawer Navigator with gestures, the text starts to be selected.

I tried changing the `state isSelectable` using `onMoveShouldSetResponder`, but my application crashed. Apparently I misunderstood how this prop works